# How do I set a custom Content-Type in Mongoose

Tags: http-headers, mongoose-web-server

I am working with the [Mongoose Embedded Web-server library](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) and usually Mongoose internally takes care of sending the correct HTTP Header responses.

But in my situation I need to send data with the `Content-Type:` header set to `font/opentype` however Mongoose is sending it with as `text/plain`.

How can I modify Mongoose to send this with the appropriate header?

Comment: How does it go with sending custom header `mg_send_header(conn, "Content-Type", "font/opentype");`

Comment: Hi RC Brand !! I got the solution for the above question. I had to make a entry for "{".otf", 4, "font/opentype"}" in static_builtin_mime_types[] in mongoose.c file. With this in place, mongoose takes care of the rest. We need not send any header explicitly.